# How to suspend an android app and then start debugging SO native library with IDA?

Tags: android, debugging, adb, reverse-engineering, ida

I'm trying to debug some Android application in IDA

Here are my steps:

1. Copy "android_server64" to /data/local/tmp on my phone
2. `adb shell "su -c chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/android_server64"`
3. `adb shell "su -c data/local/tmp/android_server64 &"`
4. `adb forward tcp:23946 tcp:23946`
5. `adb shell am start -D -S com.appname.global.android/.MainActivity`
6. Open .so library in IDA
7. Set my debugging parameters in IDA (e.g. host = localhost)
8. Debugger > Attach to process
9. Select my app from the list and try to debug it

So in step 5 I'm passing "-S" option to force running my app as suspended.
When I do that, I can see "**Waiting for debugger**" window on my phone.

And then when I try to attach to this suspended process and debug my SO file,
nothing really happends. "Waiting for debugger" window is still visible
and I can't debug my app when it is suspended.

So my question is - **how can I force my app to resume after attaching to process with IDA?**

Comment: "Waiting for debugger" means in this case "Waiting for Java debugger". You need to connect via jdb to the app to resume it. jdb and IDA can be connected at the same time.

Comment: Nice. I'll try that. :)